# Step in the proof of lemma $Pr(Y \le a) \le Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(|Y - X| > \epsilon)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let X , Y be random variables, futhermore, let a be a real number and $\epsilon > 0$.

Then we can prove the lemma $Pr(Y \le a) \le Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(|Y - X| > \epsilon)$

A proof is supplied on  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propA2) wikipedia page.

We start of by showing that due to the law of total probability that:

$Pr(Y \le a) = Pr(Y \le a , X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y \le a , X > a + \epsilon)$

The next step is to to show that:

$Pr(Y \le a , X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y \le a , X > a + \epsilon) \le Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y - X \le a - X , a - X < -\epsilon)$

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$ P(Y\le a, X\le a+\epsilon)\le P(X\le a+\epsilon)$$ since the event in the LHS is a subset of the one on the RHS and $$P(Y\le a, X>a+\epsilon)=P(Y-X\le a-X, a-X<-\epsilon) $$ since the event on the LHS is exactly the same as the one on the RHS (the only change is that the inequalities have been manipulated to equivalent ones).

Comment: Why is the event on the left hand side a subset of the one on the right hand side?

Comment: Because if $Y\le a$ *and* $X\le a+\epsilon,$ then it's certainly the case that $X\le a + \epsilon.$ (e.g. the probability that the next card is the ace of clubs is less than or equal to the probability that it is an ace.... and I don't need to know anything about what cards are left in the deck to tell you that.)

Answer (score 1):

From:
\begin{align}
&\underbrace{Pr(Y \le a , X \le a + \epsilon)}_{I} + \underbrace{Pr(Y \le a , X > a + \epsilon)}_{II}\\
&\leq \underbrace{Pr(X \le a + \epsilon)}_{III} + \underbrace{Pr(Y - X \le a - X , a - X < -\epsilon)}_{IV},
\end{align}

all it's saying is the following:

$I\leq \underbrace{Pr(Y\leq a, X\leq a +\epsilon)}_{I}+Pr(Y>a, X\leq a+\epsilon)=\underbrace{Pr(X\leq a+\epsilon)}_{III}$.

Then $II=IV$ since we can go from $II$ to $IV$ by subtracting $X$ from both sides of the $Y$ inequality and rearranging the $X$ inequality.