# Step in proof of lemma used to prove convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let X , Y be random variables, futhermore, let a be a real number and $\epsilon > 0$.

In order to prove that onvergence in probability implies convergence in distribution,

we need to prove the lemma $Pr(Y \le a) \le Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(|Y - X| > \epsilon)$.

A proof is supplied on  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propA2) wikipedia page.

We start off by showing that due to the law of total probability that:

$Pr(Y \le a) = Pr(Y \le a , X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y \le a , X > a + \epsilon)$

The next step is to to show that (see explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271191/step-in-the-proof-of-lemma-pry-le-a-le-prx-le-a-epsilon-pry-x))

$Pr(Y \le a , X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y \le a , X > a + \epsilon) \le Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y - X \le a - X , a - X < -\epsilon)$

Next, we can rearrange the inequalities in $Pr(Y - X \le a - X , a - X < -\epsilon)$ to show that:

$Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y - X \le a - X , a - X < -\epsilon) \le Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y - X \le -\epsilon)$

The next step would be to show that:

$Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y - X \le -\epsilon) \le Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(Y - X < -\epsilon) + Pr(Y - X > \epsilon) = Pr(X \le a + \epsilon) + Pr(|Y - X| > \epsilon)$

Which I assume follows from the fact that:

$Pr(Y - X \le -\epsilon) \le Pr(Y - X < -\epsilon) + Pr(Y - X > \epsilon) = Pr(|Y - X| > \epsilon)$.

But why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The event $(|X-Y|>\epsilon)$ is the disjoint union of the events $(Y-X<-\epsilon)$ and $(Y-X >\epsilon)$.  So $P(Y-X <-\epsilon) \leq P(Y-X <-\epsilon)+P(Y-X>\epsilon)=P(|Y-X| >\epsilon)$. [The first inequality is not an equality].

Comment: Also why is $Pr(Y - X \le -\epsilon) = Pr(Y - X < -\epsilon) + Pr(Y - X > \epsilon \:\:$?

Comment: You don't have equality there. It is an inequality. (Read my answer now) .@DanielDeWet

Comment: Equality in your comment is not used in the proof. You are reading the proof wrongly. Do you understand that $a \leq a+b$ if $b \geq 0$?